# Master user is deleted in RDS will terraform delete and recreate the resource?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

I have a RDS database in AWS the master user has been deleted.  My terraform plan just shows it's going to change the password. (Since the user was deleted, I gave a random password for the master user). Now when i apply the terraform plan will it delete and re-create the database?

My guess on why terraform is saying its going to change only the password because, the master user-name  is visible through the console. Also this database is an imported resource.

Please let me know your insights in this scenario , Since its a production database and I would like to be 100% sure that it does not delete and recreate the database.

```
16:55:22 data.aws_subnet_ids.subnet_groups: Refreshing state...
16:55:22 aws_db_subnet_group.xxx_subnet_group: Refreshing state... (ID: ****xxxx-name-dbsg)
16:55:22 aws_db_instance.xxxx: Refreshing state... (ID: ****xxxx)
16:55:22 
16:55:22 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
16:55:22 
16:55:22 An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
16:55:22 Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
16:55:22   ~ update in-place
16:55:22 
16:55:22 Terraform will perform the following actions:
16:55:22 
16:55:22   ~ module.rds.aws_db_instance.xxxxx
16:55:22       password: <sensitive> => <sensitive> (attribute changed)
16:55:22 
16:55:22 
16:55:22 Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Comment: What does the plan show? And can you edit your question to include a [mcve] of this with, ideally the before state and what you did to cause this state?

Comment: Ideally someone deleted the master user , i'm not sure how this happened.